# Как вывести массив numpy на печать единой строкой?

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

У меня есть такой numpy-массив:

```
Y =  [[0.9]
 [0.1]
 [0.1]
 [0.9]
 [0.1]]
```

Мне нужно, чтобы `print(Y)` выводил на печать просто строкой все значения. Вот так:

```
 0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1
```

Сейчас он выводится столбиком. Как это сделать с массивом numpy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я так понял, вам нужно вывести без скобок и с разделением по запятым:

```
import numpy

arr = numpy.array([[0.9], [0.1], [0.1], [0.9], [0.1]])
print(arr)
# [[0.9]
#  [0.1]
#  [0.1]
#  [0.9]
#  [0.1]]

print(', '.join(map(str, arr.ravel())))
# 0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1
```

Comment: Премного благодарствую! Все получилось

Answer (score 2):

Можно например, использовать метод `ravel`:

```
> print(Y.ravel())
[0.9 0.1 0.1 0.9 0.1]
```

Comment: он частично помог, снял один уровень скобок, но все равно выводится построчно:

`Y =  [0.9 0.1 0.1 0.9 0.1 0.1   
 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1   
 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1   
 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1   
 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 ]`

Comment: @Mavar, `print(*Y.ravel())`